# Getting SUM of 'x' consecutive values where x is an integer from another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to code in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. This is SQL. I have to get the sum of x previous consecutive rows where x is based on a number in another row. For Example:

[image]

Example 1:
As you can see in Row 10, the RESULT column returns the SUM of the Quantities of the 4 rows (Row 7 to 10) basing it on the Column 'Consecutive', which has the value 4. (7+7+7+9 = 30)

Example 2:
In Row 9, the RESULT column returns the SUM of the Quantities in the 2 rows, again based on the Column 'Consecutive' which has the value 2. (7+7+7 = 14)

Example 3:
In Row 8, the RESULT column returns the SUM of the Quantities in the 3 rows, again based on the Column 'Consecutive' which has the value 3. (7+7+1 = 15).

My code looked like this, but I do not know how to replace the 'Consecutive' part.

```
SUM(Quantities) OVER
(   PARTITION BY ...
        ORDER BY ...  ----This is 
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND Consecutive FOLLOWING
```

The error says

> Incorrect syntax near 'Consecutive'

Comment: Have you read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply select the needed rows for each row. Here is full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE 
(
    [Row] INT
   ,[Quantities] INT
   ,[Consecutive] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Row], [Quantities], [Consecutive])
VALUES (1, 8, 4)
      ,(2, 7, 3)
      ,(3, 7, 3)
      ,(4, 7, 2)
      ,(5, 9, 4)
      ,(6, 1, 3)
      ,(7, 7, 3)
      ,(8, 7, 3)
      ,(9, 7, 2)
      ,(10, 9, 4);

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource E
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(I.[Quantities])
    FROM @DataSource I
    WHERE I.[Row] > = E.[Row] - E.[Consecutive] + 1
        AND I.[Row] <= E.[Row]
) DS ([RESULT]);
```

[image]

Comment: May I know what the DS ([RESULT]) stand for?

Comment: It is just a alias of the data source and a name for its column. It can be any valid name. Change it to something to test.

Comment: Oh okay! Because I tried levelling it up, I tried putting categories A from Row 1 to 5, then B from Row 6 to 10. I wanted to try doing it but now in separate categories. I am unable to do the same. :( How do I do it?

Comment: @LawrenceWayneRagudo Could you ask separate question with sample data and desire output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853208/sql-getting-sum-of-x-consecutive-values-where-x-is-an-integer-in-another-row I asked it here awhile back