# SQL - Getting Sum of 'X' Consecutive Values where X is an Integer in another Row (With Categories)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

Say for example, I wanted to SUM all the values from the current row until the provided count. See table below:

[image]

For example:

- Category A, Row 1: 10+15+25 = 50 (because it adds Rows 1 to 3 due to Count)
- Category A, Row 2: 15+25+30+40 = 110 (because it adds Rows 2 to 5 due to count)
- Category A, Row 5: 40+60 = 100 (because it Adds Rows 5 and 6. Since the count is 5, but the category ends at Row 6, so instead of that, it sums all available data which is Rows 5 and 6 only, thus having a value of 100.
- Same goes for Category B.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*,
             sum(quantity) over (partition by category order by rownumber) as running_quantity,
             max(rownumber) over (partition by category) as max_rownumber
      from t
     )
select tt.*,
       coalesce(tt2.running_quantity, ttlast.running_quantity) - tt.running_quantity + tt.quantity
from tt left join
     tt tt2
     on tt2.category = tt.category and
        tt2.rownumber = tt.rownumber + tt.count - 1 left join
     tt ttlast
     on ttlast.category = tt.category and
        ttlast.rownumber = ttlast.max_rownumber
order by category, rownumber;
```

I can imagine that under some circumstances this would be much faster -- particularly if the `count` values are relatively large.  For small values of `count`, the lateral join is probably faster, but it is worth checking if performance is important.

Actually, a pure window functions approach is probably the best approach:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*,
             sum(quantity) over (partition by category order by rownumber) as running_quantity
      from t
     )
select tt.*,
       (coalesce(lead(tt.running_quantity, tt.count - 1) over (partition by tt.category order by tt.rownumber),
                 first_value(tt.running_quantity) over (partition by tt.category order by tt.rownumber desc)
                ) - tt.running_quantity + tt.quantity
       )
from tt
order by category, rownumber;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afdd797ff5733287922c8db966c79293) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE 
(
    [Category] CHAR(1)
   ,[Row Number] BIGINT
   ,[Quantity] INT
   ,[Count] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Category], [Row Number], [Quantity], [Count])
VALUES ('A', 1, 10, 3)
      ,('A', 2, 15, 4)
      ,('A', 3, 25, 2)
      ,('A', 4, 30, 1)
      ,('A', 5, 40, 5)
      ,('A', 6, 60, 2)
      --
      ,('B', 1, 12, 2)
      ,('B', 2, 13, 3)
      ,('B', 3, 17, 1)
      ,('B', 4, 11, 2)
      ,('B', 5, 10, 5)
      ,('B', 6, 7, 3);

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource E
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(I.[Quantity])
    FROM @DataSource I
    WHERE I.[Row Number] <= E.[Row Number] + E.[Count] - 1
        AND I.[Row Number] >= E.[Row Number]
        AND E.[Category] = I.[Category]
) DS ([Sum]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That did work! No problems regarding this already. My concern now is, if I have a data that is very large, the processing time is super slow (like the one I'm doing right now still executes query for over an hour now) But thank you anyways!!

Comment: @LawrenceWayneRagudo Are you reading from one table or the query is more complex?